# How can I run clips in C++?

Tags: c++, clips

How can I run clips in C++ ?

when I search in google

I found this link 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsmm/?source=dlp
but the rar file is damaged

and I read about CLIPSCPP library , but I can't found this library

Comment: It is a `bzip2`-ed `tar` archive `clipsmm-0.3.3.tar.bz2` which works fine if untarred with `tar xavf` (at least on Linux/Debian), use [GNU tar](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) to unarchive it (and install `bzip2` before); no need to use `rar`

Comment: And `clipscpp` is on http://ostatic.com/clipscpp

Answer (score 1):

Also from section 1.2 of the CLIPS Advanced Programming Guide (if you just want to directly use the CLIPS APIs from C++ rather than using wrapper classes):

1.2 C++ COMPATIBILITY

The CLIPS source code can now be compiled using either an ANSI C or C++ compiler. Minimally, non-ANSI C compilers must support full ANSI style function prototypes and the void data type in order to compile CLIPS. If you want to make CLIPS API calls from a C++ program, it is usually easier to do the integration by compiling the CLIPS source files as C++ files. This removes the need to make an extern "C" declaration in your C++ program for the CLIPS APIs. Some programming environments allow you to specify the whether a file should be compiled as C or C++ code based on the file extension. Other environments allow you to explicitly specify which compiler to use regardless of the extension (e.g. in gcc the option “-x c++” will compile .c files as C++ files). In some environments, the same compiler is used to compile both C and C++ programs and the compiler uses the file extension to determine whether the file should be compiled as a C or C++ program. In this situation, changing the .c extension of the CLIPS source files to .cpp usually allows the source to be compiled as a C++ program.